# How to change color for a block of texts?

Tags: color

I am editing a LaTeX paper with Emacs. Sometimes I want to make a block of texts less obvious (or less important to see). Instead of totally hiding them, they should still be there. Is there an easy way to embed them in something so that it changes color (to grey for instance)?

By the way, besides changing color, are there other ways to easily make a block of texts look less important?

Comment: The traditional way to de-emphasize blocks of text in an editor is called text folding (or code folding, for software).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085170/how-to-achieve-code-folding-effects-in-emacs

Comment: The question wasn't clear, but the answers seem to be focused on changing the color of the output text, not the color of the text in the editor.

Answer (score 427, accepted):

You can use the [`xcolor` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) (which can be installed via `tlmgr install xcolor`). It provides `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}` as well as `\color{<color>}` to switch the color for some give text or until the end of the group/environment. You can get different shades of gray by using `black!x` as a color where `x` is a number from 0 to 100, taken as a percentage with 100 being black.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

This is a sample text in black.
\textcolor{blue}{This is a sample text in blue.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great, \color{<color>} is what i need, thank you very much!

Comment: Just one thing, what if my block of code is embedded in \begin{align*} and \end{align*}, which is under math mode. \textcolor... or \color... work on a single word, but not on a block of words...

Comment: No, `\textcolor{green}{a couple of words}` colors the entire second argument. `\color{green}` is a declaration, which changes the text color of everything that follows (in that scope, or group as its called in TeX). It is analogous to `\textbf` versus `\bfseries`. `\color` should also work in math mode. But some of the amsmath environments do rather complicated things in order to work (reading the contents several times, for example). But then you could try `{\color{green} \begin{align*} blabla \end{align*} } (note the outer braces).

Comment: @SoftTimur: Like Villemoes said, `\color` should work in mathmode. It would be best if you give an example so we can see where the problem lies. You could edit your question for this.

Comment: I am using this right now and the color is not changing back even though I a using the form that should color only a few words.

Comment: I had to throw braces around the entire thing and skip the inner braces to get it to work.

Comment: @Elliot: This is not normal. Which class are you using? In which context are you using the macro, i.e. inside normal text or a table or a different one?

Comment: The following color names are defined: red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow, black, gray, white, darkgray, lightgray, brown, lime, olive, orange, pink, purple, teal, violet. See the package [documentation](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf).

Comment: @SoftTimur Dr. Scharrer's accepted answer is probably a better suggestion since `\textcolor` is usually a better choice unless you are setting a color for a large amount of text, such as the whole document. Please see this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86040/22810) from `TeX` guru and and an expert on the subject `David Carlisle`.

Answer (score 53):

The following seems simpler:

```
\documentclass{amsproc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    This is {\color{red} highlighted}, and this is not.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think your solution is exactly what @Martin Scharrer is suggesting?

Comment: No. @Martin Scharrer suggested using the xcolor package, whereas this answer suggests using the hyperref package.

Comment: As a side note: This solution does not change colour of a text in an equation unless `xcolor` package is used.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `\color` is not a hyperref command, but that hyperref loads color or xcolor on its own.

Answer (score 27):

All the above answers are excellent for general purpose

If you want to highlight a syntax for a programming language we can use [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted?lang=en) package, it provides excellent colored highlighted text.

To use this package you need to have [python](https://www.anaconda.com/) installed on your system (you can install python using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) package it's great choice) in addition to a package called [pygments](http://pygments.org/) (to install this package use `pip install pygments`) it's a python library used to highlight programming language syntax

I'll give a simple example of how to use it

```
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vim} %note here you can use different highlighting
                      %styles see the final note below

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

T=1
delta_T=T/200
alpha=0.5
fc=40/T
A_m=1
t=[i for i in np.arange(-5,5,1/200)]
t_arr=np.array(t)
N=len(t)

g_T=[]
for i in range(N):
    if (abs(t[i])!=(T/2*alpha)):
        g_T.append(np.sinc(t[i])*(np.cos(np.pi*alpha*t[i]/T)/
            (1- 4*alpha**2 *(t[i])**2 /(T**2))))
    else:
        g_T.append(0)
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

This code will produce the following [image: This the output of the above code]

**Note** you need to enable  " -shell-escape " option with either LaTeX or pdfLaTeX

```
latex -shell-escape foo.tex
```

or

```
pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex
```

If you want to get different highlights, on the command line use

```
pygmentize -L styles
```

You'll get different styles of highlighting

CHEERS,
 Hizzani

Comment: izzani this is awesome! :)

Answer (score 11):

Use the package

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

and right after that write this line given below :

```
\newcommand{\myRed}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

Now wherever you want to highlight some text use `\myRed{}`.

When you compile, you will get text in `\myRed` in red color.