# What is the difference between \textcolor and \color?

Tags: color

I would like to define a new command to work as an alert command. If I want to alert some part of my text I would simply write `\alert{}`. But I want the result in red color.

What is the best way to do this? I tried

```
\def\alert#1{{\color{red}{#1}}}
```

but I know that there is `\textcolor` also. I want my command to work both for text and math contents.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Despite the name `\textcolor` also works in math mode. The main difference is just one of syntax, `\textcolor` takes text as an *argument* (like `\textrm`) `\color`  affects all text to the end of the group (like `\rmfamily`). However `\textcolor` also executes `\leavevmode` which makes the color special occur in a much less destructive place as part of the paragraph rather than on a vertical list. So `\textcolor` is usually a better choice unless you are setting a colour for a large amount of text, such as the whole document.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that `color` package is required. Is there some color commands which needs only basic packages?

Comment: There is basic underlying support for colour in the latex  format but no actual top level colour commands. color is part of the required latex distribution so it is as basic as say article.cls

Comment: @Sigur I agee with David. `\textcolor` does seem to be a better choice here. See also this accepted [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17105/22810) from Dr. Scharrer.