# Using \textbf vs. \mathbf in Math mode

Tags: fonts, formatting, color

Is there any preference for using `\textbf` or `\mathbf` in math mode; or `\textbf` works exactly the same as `\mathbf` in math mode? I know for example, the `\textit` does not work in some cases in math mode, e.g. `$\textit{text1^{text2}}$` gives an error, but `$\mathit{text1^{text2}}$` is valid. On the other hand, `\textcolor` is "usually" a better choice than `\color` in math mode [Ref: This [post]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86040/22810)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Spaces are ignored in the arguments of `\mathbf` and `\mathit`, but not in the arguments of `\textbf` and `\textit`.

[image]

Also, you can't combine `\mathbf` and `\mathit`. E.g., `\mathbf{\mathit{xyz}}` produces *xyz* rather than ***xyz***.

And, of course, the outputs of `\mathbf` and `\textbf` will differ if you use different fonts for math-mode and text-mode material.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\textbf{abc def}$ 

$\mathbf{abc def}$

$\textit{abc def}$

$\mathit{abc def}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you all. All of the responses deserve credits since they all provided additional information. I've concluded that I, by enlarge, should use mathbf when in math mode.

Answer (score 12):

`\textbf` uses the text font (Libertine in the example) and `\mathbf` uses the math font (computer modern) -- same happens for `\textrm` and `\mathrm`. Libertine has no math, the reason why TeX takes the default math font. And, of course, text and math font maybe looking very different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}

$\textbf{some text}~\mathbf{some text}~some text$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note, that if you happen to use `unicode-math`, then `\mathbf` will indeed use the text-font. They introduced a new command `\symbf` to use the math-font. See the documentation for a discussion of this topic.

Answer (score 11):

To extend Herberts answer, the `\textbf` furthermore keeps the “surrounding” font style, for example when using a theorem, which typesets its content in italics, so will the `\textbf` will set the text bold *and* italic, while `\mathbf` will not only use the math font but furthermore *only* the bold font and not an italic one.

For example with

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    In normal text
    \[
        \mathbf{A}\textbf{B}
    \]
    \begin{thm}
    In theorems, or other italic texts
    \[
        \mathbf{A}\textbf{B}
    \]
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

The result is
[image]which might or might not be what you want (for example when defining own commands).

Answer (score 9):

The technical difference are described here
[Difference between \textrm{} and \mathrm{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22350/difference-between-textrm-and-mathrm/22353#22353)

But more important is the semantic difference: `\text...` commands switch to text mode, and so they should be used, if you want to write *text*, that means words like "and" or "it follows that" etc. `\math...` commands write math, and so should be used for variables with mathematical meaning. Normally there argument is short -- only one char, sometimes some more as e.g. `V_{\mathrm{max}}`.

Comment: Completely agree. But just a small addition: if instead of `V_{\mathrm{max}}` one wants to write `V_{\mathrm{máx}}` one might need to use *as an exception* in that particular case `V_{\textnormal{máx}}` (I used `\textnormal` but the same applies to others).