# Komascript - Section after pagebreak has the wrong color

Tags: sectioning, color, koma-script

The following MWE shows that the second `section` is black instead of red. Even if this happens only if there is no text between these two sections: Is this a bug?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\addtokomafont{section}{\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
...
\\[0.84\textheight]
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just found out that the page break between sections will never happen if I use `\textcolor` instead of `\color`. Looks like `\textcolor` is more stable: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86039/what-is-the-difference-between-textcolor-and-color

Comment: `\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\large\bfseries\sffamily\color{red}]{section}`

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you want to say that `\addtokomafont` should not be used for the text color?

Comment: I am saying that the above abviously works but has some downsides. You should report the behaviour to komascript.de

Comment: I would consider that a duplicate.

Comment: @Johannes_B `\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\large\color{red}]{section}` does the same as `\setkomafont{section}{ \large\color{red}}`. Note that the default size for `section` in `scrartcl` is `\Large` and not `\large`.

Comment: @StefanBraun `\color{red}` is allowed in `\addtokomafont`, `\setkomafont` and as value for the `font` option in `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. AFAIK the problem will be solved in the next KOMA-Script version (3.21).

Comment: @esdd But with `\Redeclare...` i didn't get the odd behaviour (2016/05/10 v.3.20).

Comment: @Johannes_B In your suggestion `\large` is used. Change it to `\Large` (default for sections in `scrartcl`) and you get the page break and the black color.

Comment: @esdd Ok, now i now what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: @StefanBraun You can use/test the prerelease of version 3.21 from http://www.komascript.de/node/1801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is fixed in KOMA-Script Version 3.21 which is the current version on CTAN, in TeX Live 2016 and in MiKTeX.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2016/06/14]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\addtokomafont{section}{\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
...
\\[0.84\textheight]
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should use \leavevmode before the color command. This will avoid that a page break can occur between the color and the title of the section.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\addtokomafont{section}{\leavevmode\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
...
\\[0.84\textheight]
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]