# unexpected behaviour of \addtokomafont

Tags: koma-script

Regarding the following two examples my question is: Is it a bug or is it a feature (or do I miss something)?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \addtokomafont{sectioning}{\color{green}}
 \addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{green}}
 \addtokomafont{section}{\color{green}}
 \addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{green}}
 \addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\color{green}}

\setlength{\textheight}{13\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

AAA

\section{test}

\subsection{subtest}

AAA
\end{document}
```

Please compare the results [sorry, I can not upload images] of the examples.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \addtokomafont{sectioning}{\color{green}}
% \addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{green}}
% \addtokomafont{section}{\color{green}}
% \addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{green}}
% \addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\color{green}}

\setlength{\textheight}{13\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

AAA

\section{test}

\subsection{subtest}

AAA
\end{document}
```

The former one shows a page break between `\section` and `\subsection`.

Comment: Unexpected, but not weird: you are issuing `\color` in vertical mode, which is always dangerous. The two examples differ in when the color change is performed.

Comment: Ok, but this is the procedure which is recommended. And on the first sight I would not expect any differences between `\addtokomafont{sectioning}` and `\addtokomafont{section}` and so on.

Comment: `\leavevmode` We already have a similar question.

Comment: Which KOMA-Script Version do you use? With version 3.21 or 3.22 (current on CTAN and in the distributions) I do not get a page break between between `\section` and `\subsection`. But with version 3.20 I can reproduce the described behavior. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314235/43317 and http://www.komascript.de/release3.20 (German).

Comment: Many thanks, that's it! Would you like to put this into an answer or should we close this one with reference to 43317 or should I post the answer or ...?

Comment: BTW: Yes, I am still on Version 3.20. Perhaps I should update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an uptodate KOMA-Script (at least version 3.21, current is 3.22) I do not get a page break between `\section` and `\subsection`.

Even if I use

```
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{blue}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{red}}
```

the result is

[image]

So you have to update your KOMA-Script version.

---

Workaround for version 3.20 or older:

You can add `\nobreak` after the `\color` command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\color{green}\nobreak}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{blue}\nobreak}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{red}\nobreak}

\setlength{\textheight}{13\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\section{test}
\subsection{subtest}
AAA
\end{document}
```

or `\leavevmode` before `\color` (see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314235/43317)):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\leavevmode\color{green}}% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314243/43317
\addtokomafont{section}{\leavevmode\color{blue}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\leavevmode\color{red}}

\setlength{\textheight}{13\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\section{test}
\subsection{subtest}
AAA
\end{document}
```

Both results in

[image]