# Coloring part of text failed

Tags: formatting, color

I want to color the number 2 in my formula in red using the following:

```
\textrm{var}(X) = \frac{(b−a)(b−a+\color{red}{2})}{12}
```

However, what I got is:

[image: img]

Can someone show me a fix for that?

Comment: Use `\textcolor` instead of `\color` (`\color` is a *declaration*). Please add a minimal working example to your question.

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86039/73317) for more explanations. Can we consider this a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

From your `MWE` understood that you need color only for the text 2, but now the parenthesis also comes in color, if my assumption correct, try the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\[
\textrm{var}(X) = \frac{(b-a)(b-a+{\color{red}{2}})}{12}
\]
\end{document}
```

Just introduce an extra grouping will solve the issue

Comment: Hi!  I am using Auto-LaTex add-on for Google Docs.  That formula does not render right with it.  Do you have any pointer?

Comment: @J.Doe Sorry, I don't know enough about `Auto-LaTeX add-on for Google Docs`...