# How do I change text color?

Tags: color, text-decorations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change color for a block of texts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17104/how-to-change-color-for-a-block-of-texts)

Wanting to change the text on the contacts frame from black to white.

```
\documentclass[T]{beamer}
\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Presentation Template}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white}
\author{Author 1\\Author2}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=white}
\date\today
\begin{document}
{\usebackgroundtemplate
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{titlepage}}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\section*{Outline}
{\usebackgroundtemplate
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{caessubslide}}
\begin{frame}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \frametitle{Contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{multicols} 
\end{frame}
\section{Contact Information}
{\usebackgroundtemplate
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{caestitlepage}}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item CONTACT1
\item CONCTACT2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: exact duplicate of this one I think: [How to change color for a block of texts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17104)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

why not use the `xcolor` package?

Normally

```
\textcolor{black}{text}
```

should do what you want

for the whole `itemize`

```
{\color{black}\begin{itemize}
    \item
    \item
\end{itemize}}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I typed \usepackage{xcolor} in the preable and used your second suggestion to no avail.

Comment: but the \textcolor{}{text} worked.  Thanks.

Comment: The second option does not work in beamer.