# Using color with \marginpar

Tags: color

I'm using the package `marvosym` and the triangle symbol `\Rewind` with `\marginpar`. To draw attention to the symbol, I would like to have it be in red. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Shomu. I think your question may have been answered before: see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17105/25356).

Answer (score 3):

Load the `xcolor` package, and use `\textcolor{red}{\Rewind}`. For more information, [[here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors)] is a good reference.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{\Rewind}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]