# How to save the current colour

Tags: color

If I want to gray out large swaths of text in a report, I know that I can use the `xcolor` package's \color{black!50} command:
[How to change color for a block of texts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17104/how-to-change-color-for-a-block-of-texts)
http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/latex/use-font-colors-in-latex-documents

Is there any way to confirm that the default color is indeed black before I issue the above command?

In a related search, I found that I can even push the current colour onto a stack:
http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/colours.html

However, that page is from 1997, targets slides, and uses a different package.  I am currently very bound to the `xcolor` package.

This question has been posted at:
[How to save the current colour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218090/how-to-save-the-current-colour)
http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=25431

Comment: actually xcolor rather than color package (for the `!50` syntax)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Package `xcolor` has the concept of a "current color" with the dot as name. With `\colorlet` it can be saved:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
...
\begin{document}
...
\colorlet{saved}{.}
\color{black!50}
...
\color{saved}
```

Or grouping can be used, which also works with LaTeX's `color` package:

- small text: `\textcolor{black!50}{...}`
- larger chunks including paragraphs:

  ```
  \begingroup
    \color{black!50}
    ...
  \endgroup
  ```

  (Also curly braces can be used for grouping.)

Comment: Thanks, Heiko.  I didn't realize it, but our organizational template loads up the xcolor package.  I thought I was using the color package.  Probably I was, if xcolor loads the color package.