# Sans serif upright greek in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, greek

I need to write a document with the Helvetica font and found **sansmathfonts** to be good matching counterpart for math, but I'm open for other suggestions.

Now I'm really struggling to get **sans serif upright greek** letters in math-mode. Is there any way to achieve that?

For serif fonts I was previously using either  **upgreek** or this [**great answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277577/36835). Both are not working for helvet+sansmathfonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

Upright greek in math mode:
$\mathrm{\mu\alpha\beta\gamma}$, $\upmu\upalpha\upbeta\upgamma$, 

\end{document}
```

---

MWE regarding Steven B. Segletes comment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.2]{%
  \mkern1mu%
  \ThisStyle{\slantbox[#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}}%
  \mkern-1mu%
}

\newcommand\upmu{\unslant\mu} 

\begin{document}

Upright greek in math mode: $\mathrm{\mu}$, $\upmu$, 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[color=red,] {$\upmu$$\mu$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using pdflatex (which it seems you are not), my answer here is a direct fix: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220. (Note: for this font, set the default `\unslant` optional argument value to `-.2`)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It actually works also with lualatex. The problem I always have with this solution when used with tikz (I tried it in multiple situations in the past) is that the letters do not adapt the color of nodes. Do you know how to fix that? I updated my MWE.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes By the way, you should make it a package ;)

Comment: Well, a workaround is surely `\node {\textcolor{red}{$\upmu$$\mu$}};`

Comment: I think that would make a good question as to why `\slantbox` does not take on a `tikz` node's color.  It obeys `\textcolor` and `\color` outside of `tikz`,  For something real interesting, try `\node[color=red,] {$\upmu$$\mu$ and \textcolor{red}{$\upmu$}$\mu$};`

Comment: Perhaps related: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/362/

Comment: Until the `pgf` bug can be fixed, a workaround/fix for `\slantbox` that works in `tikz` is this: `\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\colorlet{slantcolor}{.}\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{\color{slantcolor}#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}`, using the technique described by Heiko here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218090/how-to-save-the-current-colour

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes this seems a good solution! May you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer comes following discussion in the comments to the question, to which I refer the reader.  I pointed out that my solution at [Upright Greek font fitting to Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220) works directly at unslanting a font (it is based on Bruno's answer at [Shear transform a "box"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188)). I show there how to apply it to greek letter forms, but noted that it only applies to pdflates, whereas the OP had lualatex invocations in the preamble.

The OP then tells me that the `\unslant` method works in lua as well (halle-lua-jah), but that the underlying `\slantbox` has a problem accepting the color of `tikz` nodes.  That was news to me, since `\slantbox` accepts color just fine as part of a `\textcolor` argument, or following a `\color` declaration.

I then came across a pgf bug report, https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/362/, that would seem to be related to the problem.  Since I can't solve that problem myself, I looked for a workaround.

Heiko's answer at [How to save the current colour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218090/how-to-save-the-current-colour) shows a cool technique of `\colorlet{slantcolor}{.}` to save the current color (before going into the `\mbox`, and then I just re-issued a `\color{slantcolor}` inside the `\foobox`.  That seemed to fix the problem.

To recap, the `\unslant` method allows existing *italic* letters to be made upright in the same font design, and the `\colorlet` fix allows this solution to work with colored `tikz` nodes.  The overall approach works with pdflatex and lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\colorlet{slantcolor}{.}\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{\color{slantcolor}#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.2]{%
  \mkern1mu%
  \ThisStyle{\slantbox[#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}}%
  \mkern-1mu%
}
\newcommand\upmu{\unslant\mu} 
\begin{document}
Upright greek in math mode: $\mathrm{\mu}$, $\upmu$, 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[color=red,] {$\upmu$$\mu$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Are you aware of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277571/create-and-use-macro-names-dynamically-within-a-loop-for-redefining-lowercase-gr/277577#277577)? It makes a great addition to you unslant approach as it recognizes also `\mathrm`.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thank you.  And no, I was not aware of the answer, though I am certainly aware of wipet's proficiency at such things.  That looks like a really useful approach.

Comment: I have two questions: (1) Does this work with any sans serif font? (2) What’s the purpose of the scaling in `\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}`?

Comment: And two more, if you don’t mind: (3) Why do `\Bbb` and `\mathbb` not work when I use this preamble? (4) Why does `\mathbf` not seem to do anything to Greek letters?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish 1) To use `\mathbb`, you need `\usepackage{amssymb}`. 2) The `scale=` literally scales the font size uniformly (as I understand it), because for some reason, the `helvet` font seemed too large to the OP.  3) As to `\mathbf`, not all fonts have a bold version...generally, greek math letters do not.  4) Finally, `\slantbox` should work with any font.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Actually yeah, it kinda does look weird. If I delete the scaling, the regular text is noticeably larger than the math. In fact, even with the scaling, it's still noticeable. `x` and `$x$` don't render at the same height until the scale is set to `0.85` in fact.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CB fonts

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{sfgreek}{LGR}{cmss}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{sfgreek}{bold}{LGR}{cmss}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`b}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`g}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`d}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`e}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`h}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`j}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`i}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`k}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`l}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omicron}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`o}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`r}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`s}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`t}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`u}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`f}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`w}
\let\varepsilon\epsilon
\let\vartheta\theta
\let\varpi\pi
\let\varrho\rho
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathord}{sfgreek}{`c}
\let\varphi\phi
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{sfgreek}{`W}



\begin{document}

Upright greek in math mode:
$\mu\alpha\beta\gamma$

$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\zeta\eta\theta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu$

$\nu\xi\omicron\pi\rho\sigma\varsigma\tau\upsilon\phi\chi\psi\omega$

$\mathrm{A}\mathrm{B}\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Lambda\Xi\Pi\Sigma\Upsilon\Phi\Psi\Omega$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you declare the math symbols like `\DeclareMathSymbol{\upGamma}{ ...` than you can combine it with [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277577/36835) - which is great. Thank you!

Comment: Your use of `\let\varepsilon\epsilon` etc means there is no varepsilon provided by the font?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Correct

Comment: @egreg This is a wonderful solution. I was wondering whether there is some version for cmbr instead of cmss... by browsing the babel folder (e.g. in `lib/texmf/tex/generic/babel`) it seems that there is everything (cmr, cmtt, even cmro...) but cmbr... I'm wondering why...

Comment: @MonteCarlo The problem are the lowercase letters, I'm not sure there is support for them with cmbr.