# How to typeset a sans-serif \pi?

Tags: symbols, sans-serif

I would like to have different versions of `$\pi$`, to distinguish between them.
However, commands like `$\mathsf{\pi}$` don't alter the appearance of `pi` as compared to just `$\pi$`. Similarly for `$\texttt{\pi}$`.
Could you tell me if there is any way to get different pi's?

Comment: Relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313934/sans-serif-upright-greek-in-math-mode

Answer (score 4):

Adapting the solution by [[egreg (2016)]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313959/10995), we define `\sfpi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{sfitgreek}{LGR}{cmss}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{sfitgreek}{bold}{LGR}{cmss}{bx}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sfpi}{\mathord}{sfitgreek}{`p}
\begin{document}
$\pi \sfpi$
\end{document}
```

[image]