# How to colour just one link with hyperref package?

Tags: hyperref, color, urls, links

I'm using the `hyperref` package with the `hidelinks` option, but there is one link I would like to be coloured and I'm trying to do this with an overriding `hypersetup` command in an environment which only contains that particular link. Why doesn't this work?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{stackexchange.com}{hide this link}\\
{\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}{\href{stackexchange.com}{do not hide this link}}}\\
\href{stackexchange.com}{hide this link}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The method works just as intended the other way round:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
\href{stackexchange.com}{do not hide this link}\\
{\hypersetup{hidelinks}{\href{stackexchange.com}{hide this link}}}\\
\href{stackexchange.com}{do not hide this link}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please consider accepting one of the answers (most likely Ulrike's straightforward answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/636731/) if it solved your problem.

Comment: @marquinho Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

colorlinks is currently a preamble only option (this changes if you use the new pdfmanagement). If you want only one link in color I suggest to use simply \color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\href{stackexchange.com}{hide this link}\\
{\color{red}{\href{stackexchange.com}{do not hide this link}}}\\
\href{stackexchange.com}{hide this link}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense of course. What if I want no different font colour, but just a coloured box around the link, as in my above example?

Comment: `\hypersetup{pdfborder={1 1 1}}`

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `\hypersetup` is actually intended only for the preamble, and I'm somewhat surprised that your first example (where you invoked `\hypersetup` in the document body) worked at all.

[**EDIT**: As Ulrike Fischer points out, `\hypersetup` does work in the document body, but not for all options; f.i., `colorlinks` works only in the preamble.]

Under my assumption that `\hypersetup{colorlinks}` is *not* expected to work in the document body, I propose the following workaround:

(1) Save the current text color [using pkg `xcolor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218091) under a custom name (`saved`), in order to retrieve it later. Normally, the text color will be `black`, but we are going for a flexible enough solution;

(2) In the preamble, set the color of all links to said default text color (`allcolors=saved`), effectively mimicking the option `hidelinks` of `hyperref`;

(3) In the document, set *locally* (within a group) the color for all links to the desired color (similarly to your own approach).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{saved}{.}  % saves the current text color as "saved"

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=saved}

\begin{document}

\href{stackexchange.com}{hide this link}

{\hypersetup{allcolors=magenta}{\href{stackexchange.com}{do not hide this link}}}

\href{stackexchange.com}{hide this link}

\end{document}
```

[image: colored link among black text]

And this is with a default text color other than `black` (setting `\color{blue}` in the preamble):

[image: colored link among blue text]

Comment: \hypersetup can be used in the document, but not all options work, colorlinks is  one that currently works only when set in the preamble.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I have edited in the information!